# How to make a div with two div inside?

Tags: html, tags

I'm learning html and I'm trying to do something like a panel with photos of people and some data about that person, for example, name, email, phone number etc. I don't know how to do this, how to put a div inside other.

how can I do for make a html code who generates something like in this image?
The "big" div with some color, and this one contains two "invisible" div, one for the image and the other for the information about the person.
[image: Iluatration]

PS.: The website is on the platform: sites.google.com (can't change for while, have to use this)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use css attribute `display: inline-block` on the div's you wish to place next to each other, or `float: right` or left. I prefer `display`.

Comment: My website is a google site (sites.google.com), so I have to upload the image there and it generates this: 

<div style="display: block; text-align: left;"><a href="https://sites.google.com/site/hpcmobilerobotics/team/blue-user-icon.png" imageanchor="1"><img src="/site/hpcmobilerobotics/team/blue-user-icon.png" border="0"></a></div>
&nbsp; <br>


Do you know how can I modify this for make like you said?

Comment: Yes, where it says `display: block` change it to `display: inline-block` and you might have to get rid of that `<br>` too...

Comment: I did. I changed to inline-block and I erased the <br>. Copy and paste after, now I have two images on the same line. And what about the text? How can I create the div near to each image with text and more important, how can I delimitate for two "combos" (image + text) for line?

Comment: That depends how you wish your image to be layed out. Do you wish the text to continue under the image or always stay on the side? If you wish it to go under it, you would put `float: left` css on the image only (and additionally some margin) but not necessarily any css on the text itself. Although if you want the text to always remain on it's own side, you'd do the same as on these div's and use `display: inline-block`. Here's an example using `float` http://imagecss.com/left.html

Comment: Ok. I'll try here. I'll choose this answer, but, is that a problem if I try first? Just in case I have some more doubts. (I hope not) :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, try what first?

Answer (score 1):

You can create two container div's , and put two divs inside their html.  In the css, the container div's will be ordered vertically by default, which means you should apply `float: left;` for each container and for each div inside them.

**http://jsfiddle.net/LA7js/**

```
<div class="left-container">
  <div class="image-left"></div>
  <div class="info-left"></div>
</div>

<div class="right-container">
  <div class="image-right"></div>
  <div class="info-right"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Like I said above, the website is a google one (sites.google.com) so I had to update the image there. It generates the code: <div style="display: block; text-align: left;"><a href="https://sites.google.com/site/hpcmobilerobotics/team/blue-user-icon.png" imageanchor="1"><img src="/site/hpcmobilerobotics/team/blue-user-icon.png" border="0"></a></div>
&nbsp; <br>

Could you explain how can I mix this with what you said?

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left">
        <div class="image"></div>
        <div class="contactInfo"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        <div class="image"></div>
        <div class="contactInfo"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
  /*width and height of main container */
  width: 1000px;
  height:400px;
}

#left, #right {
  float:left;
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
}

div.image {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

div.contactInfo {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

The numbers for height and width are total BS for this.. but you get the idea. Play with the numbers. CSS is your friend :)

Comment: I don't know if it's possible to have access to css code on google sites, it is possible?

Comment: I've never used google sites but I'm 99% sure you can access the css codes.