# how to dispaly div element side by side

Tags: html

div element is block element and default display property is block , to display it in line , inline-block property can be used.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Pictures</title>
  <style type="text/css">
  .row {
      height: 50px;
      width: 50px;
    }
    
    .row1 {
      padding-bottom: 12px;
      display: inline-block;
      float: left;
      padding-right: 14px;
    }
    
    .row2 {
      display: inline-block;
    }
  }
  #img1 {
    max-width: 50%;
    max-height: 20%;
  }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="row1">
        <!--img height="50px" width="50px" src="images/image1.jpg"-->
        hello
      </div>
      <div class="row2">
        Beutiful picture clicked by photographer
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I don't understand why these 2 divs are not getting display side by side , i am using inline-block but still no help.

Comment: they are being constrained by the parent `div class='row'` - it's width is forcing them into a vertical stacking layout

Comment: see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19260725/how-to-make-a-div-with-two-div-inside

Answer (score 0):

It is because the .row has width so less such that it can't accomodate both div. Try this it will make both parallel.

```
.row {
  height: 50px;
  width: 1000px;
}
```

Comment: @Rakesh Bagaria Please accept the answer for the question and close it